# Count number of special character combination of delimiters

Tags: awk, special-characters, aix, records

I have a very large file which has columns delimited by the `|^` special characters.

One important thing to be noted is that i am on an **AIX server**

An example of the data would be:

```
name|^surname|^age|^city|^country
john|^doe|^15|^chicago|^usa
george|^reese|^14|^london|^england
```

After searching the internet the best thing that i found is the following

```
cat TEST_FILE.DAT | awk -F"\|\^" '{ print NF }'
```

However this returns always `1` because it does not recognize the `2` characters as `1` string

The following command return the correct number of delimiters but i want to do this with the combination of `|^` as a delimiter

```
cat TEST_FILE.DAT | awk -F"|" '{ print NF }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\\` instead of `\` works for me. Not sure why exactly. Probably related to how escape characters are interpreted in bash, awk and awk's regex engine but I'm unable to give a good explanation.

```
$ cat test
name   | ^surname| ^age | ^city    | ^country
john   | ^doe    | ^15  | ^chicago | ^usa
george | ^reese  | ^14  | ^london  | ^england

$ cat test |awk -F'\\| \\^' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i)print $i}}'
name   
surname
age 
city    
country
john   
doe    
15  
chicago 
usa
george 
reese  
14  
london  
england
```

By the way, it's important to use single quotes for `-F`. This line also works but it's ugly:

```
cat test |awk -F"\\\\| \\\\^" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i)print $i}}'
```

Comment: i confirm that this worked for me in the following way `cat TEST_FILE.DAT | awk -F'\\|\\^' '{ print NF }'` thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
awk  -F'[|]\\^' '{print NF}' file
```

or

```
awk  -F'[|][\\^]' '{print NF}' file
```